# how to undo the conversion without using JSON decode?

Tags: php, json, decode, encode

When i use json_encode when he turns accents and other characters: \uXXXX

I need to catch this sequence and undo but I can not use json_decode ...

which way to do? 
thank you

Comment: What's wrong with `json_decode()`?

Comment: nothing, I just have a lot of entries and I am merging a system that must use preg, so I have to undo the conversion... can you help?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you're trying to achieve. This has the feel of an _xy_ question.

Comment: I have this entry: **"\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa"** encoded with json_encode and I need to undo the encoding to return the original value: **áéíóú**

Comment: I do not get it. If you undo the encoding then the JSON becomes invalid. If you want to decode it in order to access the "áéíóú" then why do you not `json_decode` it and then access it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your problem. See this:

```
<?php
$text = '["\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa"]'; // enclosed string in brackets for valid JSON
$arr = json_decode($text);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "áéíóú"
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://ideone.com/mo7SIl)

Comment: I used json_encode to encode (áéíóú) and teno the result: **"\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa"** and just need to get **\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa** and transform back into **áéíóú** but without using json_decode

Comment: So you keep saying, but you haven't explained why you need to do this when `json_decode()` will do the job for you.

Comment: which function encodes **áéíóú** in **\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa**?